# Why are Samsung NAND flash memory chips so hard to find?

Tags: flash, nand-flash, buying

I'm looking at NAND flash memory chips for a home project I'm working on.

There seems to be quite a few manufacturers available, Micron seems a good choice (even though a lot of their chips, mostly the small ones, are asynchronous).

But Samsung chips seems impossible to find anywhere. Not on Mouser, not on Digikey, not on Farnell. Am I missing something?
Even their website doesn't seem to list anything. Are they only selling in big quantities?

Surely a lot of companies need to get their hands on low quantities for prototyping, right?

Comment: I imagine that if you normally buy *large* quantities, you call your rep and ask for a bunch - and that's if they don't offer you them before you ask. You probably get new products before they hit the market, too.

Comment: The *big* players in the market can indeed get small quantities of devices for prototyping from the usual vendor including Samsung. Their definition of small quantities will differ from yours though in all likelihood (hundreds if not thousands).

Comment: Where I work, a first small prototype run can easily be in the 100's of units depending on the nature of the device and how confident we are in the design. Worrying about whether the MOQ is a full reel or not is often a non-issue. Makes a big difference from my early days in the industry when prototype runs were 2-5 units and part selection was often based on small quantity availability...